# Update jest snapshot with testPathPattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I use the following command to run my tests located in utils file.

```
npm t -- --testPathPattern=utils.spec.js
```

If i want to update ALL my snapshots i use

```
npm t -- -u
```

But how can i update only snapshot in `utils.spec.js` file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Following the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/cli.html#updatesnapshot)

> Use this flag to re-record every snapshot that fails during this test
>   run. Can be used together with a test suite pattern or with
>   --testNamePattern to re-record snapshots.

it should be

```
npm t -- --testPathPattern=utils.spec.js -u
```